# strip out array from wpdb get_col query results?

Tags: wordpress

How can I get this function to return just a value, rather than an array?

```
$results = $newdb->get_col( "SELECT ItemID, Price FROM $table WHERE ItemID = $quanid GROUP BY Price ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1", 1 );
```

This is the result when I `print_r( $result );` :

```
Array ( [0] => 40 )
```

This is what I need:

```
40
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

`$wpdb->get_var()`

If you have more results than one, you'll get the first one.

Answer (score 0):

Echo Sresult['0'];  to print only data stored in array index 0